# Routing in .net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Am trying to re-route my url request via my mvc code. On my local system. I use localhost/site, i want to be able to use test.localhost/site, gain.localhost/site etc and they should all point to localhost/site. Is that possible if yes C# or vb.net code samples will be really appreciated. I've been researching this for the past one week now and really need help for the community.

Comment: Could you use your hosts file to point `test.localhost` and `gain.localhost` to the same IP address as `localhost`?

Comment: Nope. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

//In the RouteConfig.cs Add 2 methods like that

```
public static void PeopleRoute(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        DBContext db = new DBContext();

        List<Instructor> instructors = db.Instructors.ToList();

        foreach (Instructor ins in instructors)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Instructor_" + ins.UserName,
                url: ins.UserName,
                defaults: new { controller = "People", action = "Details", id = ins.UserName }
            );
        }
    }

    public static void RefreshRouteTable()
    {
        // This method should be called when
        // 1) A new instructor is added
        // 2) An existing instructor is deleted
        // 3) Username of an existing instructor is changed.
        RouteTable.Routes.Clear();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

That functions are gives NEW ROUTES for the Instructor NAMES . So you should try a thing like that.